# Calculus integral evaluation using substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, logarithms

I have to find this integral:

> Evaluate the integral using an appropriate substitution $$\int\dfrac{8e^x+7e^{-x}}{8e^x-7e^{-x}}\mathrm dx.$$

I've tried my solution $\ln\Big[15\cdot \sinh(x) + \cosh(x)\Big]$, however, it is wrong.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Which u-substitution did you try?

Comment: I used u-substitution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:** The top is the derivative of the bottom. So let the bottom be $u$.

Comment: So, is the answer ln(8e^x-7e^-x) + C?

Comment: Basically yes. More precisely, to take care of cases where $8e^x-7e^{-x}\lt 0$, use $\ln(|8e^x-7e^{-x}|)+C$.

Comment: You are welcome.